# check if select box options dupilcates more than a specific times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that contain html :

```
<input class="empcode" type="text">

<!--this select box options is fielled out from database but for example 
 data like this -->

<select class="select1">
 <option value ="05-2018">05-2018</option>
 <option value ="05-2018">05-2018</option>
 <option value ="06-2018">05-2018</option>
</select>

<select class="result">
 <option value= "1">1</option>
 <option value= "1">1</option>
 <option value= "1">1</option>
</select>
```

i need when select box with class "select1" has month value repeated more than two times disable Select box with class "result"
i tried the following :

```
function HasDuplicateValues() {
 var Duplicates = false;
 $('#select1 option').each(function () {
 var $SameValue = $('#select1 option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']');
 Duplicates = $SameValue.length > 2);
 alert('dublicates')

 };
});
```

any help !!

Comment: Your JS and HTML do not match. You have a selector targeting the id `#select` but nothing with `id="select"` in your HTML. And how is `HasDuplicateValues` called?

Comment: You need to replace `#select` with `#select1` as that is the class name associated to the `select`

Comment: It should be `.select1`.

Comment: Why don't you fix the application that creates the select options so it doesn't create duplicates in the first place?

Comment: yes, sorry i forget to change class's names because i was test it before but forget to change . and also i am a begineer in javascript, i find this code on site while i searching. so please if some one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide ".result" if ".select1" has more than 2 equal options.

```js
$('.select1 option').each(function (k,v) {
  var value = $(v).attr('value');
  var SameValue = $('.select1 option[value=' + value + ']');
  if(SameValue.length > 2){
    $('.result').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="empcode" type="text">

<!--this select box options is fielled out from database but for example 
 data like this -->

<select class="select1">
 <option value ="05-2018">05-2018</option>
 <option value ="05-2018">05-2018</option>
 <option value ="05-2018">05-2018</option>
</select>

<select class="result">
 <option value= "1">1</option>
 <option value= "1">1</option>
 <option value= "1">1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 function HasDuplicateValues() {
            var Duplicates = false;
            $('select[class=select1] option').each(function () {
                var $SameValue = $('select[class=select1] option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']');
                Duplicates = $SameValue.length > 2;
                if(Duplicates)//if appears more than 2 times
                {
                    $('select[class=result]').prop('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable result select
                }
            });
```

}